# Как запустить консольную команду (npm) из кода php?

Tags: php, laravel, npm, exec

Я пытаюсь выполнить команду `npm --version` из php. Пробовал использовать стандартный [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php) и [Process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#usage) от Symfony. Вот собственно код:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class Home extends Controller
{
    public function main()
    {
        dd([
            'Via exec:'    => $this->tryRunNpmViaExec(),
            'Via process:' => $this->tryRunNpmViaProcess()
        ]);
    }

    public function tryRunNpmViaExec()
    {
        return shell_exec('npm --version 2>&1');
    }

    public function tryRunNpmViaProcess()
    {
        $process = new Process(['npm', '--version']);
        $process->run();

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            return $process->getErrorOutput();
        }

        return $process->getOutput();
    }
}
```

На выходе в браузере получаю следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот я вызываю ту же самую команду `npm --version` из терминала phpStorm и командной строки Windows:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть значения переменной среды PATH у меня настроены и любые npm команды работают, но только не при выполнении из php. С чем это может быть связано и как я могу это исправить?

Comment: Покажите как node в PATH прописан

Comment: @InDevX [Вот так](https://yadi.sk/i/ypmXstkMJr3AaQ).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php), чтобы выполнять команды.
Первым аргументом передается сама команда, для выполнения, а вторым аргументом output (вывод) выполнения команды. Также, если задать третий параметр, то можно получить статус выполнения команды. Ниже переделан Ваш код под функцию exec()

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
class Home extends Controller
{
    public function main()
    {
        dd($this->tryRunNpmViaExec());
    }

    public function tryRunNpmViaExec()
    {
        return exec('npm --version');
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Так я тоже пытался. Что через shell_exec, что через exec, что через Process результат один: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: Тогда это значит, что из среды выполнения php-скриптов npm не виден. Какой веб-сервер Вы используете?

Comment: @Nick Open Server 5.3.7 с модулями: Apache_2.4 и PHP 7.2. Но я не думаю, что проблема в сервере.

Comment: @фuɔumжεvоıqжʎuɯɹфʚd Все правильно, open server использует свой php интерпретатор и соответственно не может получить доступ к PATH. Исходя из этого вам остается найти полный путь до npm (посмотрите в PATH) и вызвать его в команде. Должно получиться что-то вроде `exec('C:/...путь до нпм.../npm.exe --version');`

Comment: @Nick `exec('cd C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm && npm --version');` - Вы про это? Такой вариант уже пробовал и он действительно подходит для вызова команды `npm --version`, но мне нужно именно заставить php видеть переменные npm/node в PATH.

Comment: @фuɔumжεvоıqжʎuɯɹфʚd, вряд ли получится использовать переменные среды windows в openserver, поэтому на Вашем месте я бы попробовал использовать docker :)